# gcc include path for tensorflow

Tags: c++, gcc, tensorflow

As I use a linter that uses gcc I want to include some files from tensorflow into my linter config so that gcc can find them. For some reason it's not very clear to me how I can achieve this. My projectstructure looks like this

**Path to my project root dir**:

> tensorflow/tensorflow/my-classifier

**Path to some other c++ .h files from tensorflow:**

> tensorflow/tensorflow/cc/**
>
> tensorflow/tensorflow/core/**

In my project root dir I have i.e. a file that includes a tensorflow header file like this:

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"
```

So gcc will somehow search:

> PROJECT_ROOT/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h

As I use bazel to build, this files will later be included into the build and the compiler will find it without any problem.

But how can I get those files included into gcc for linting purposes?

I tried it using these gcc include flags without any success:

> -I../core/**
>
> -I../cc/**

and the absoulte path.

Can someone give me a hint how the right configuration for this would be?

Comment: What linter do you use? Is it PC-lint?

Comment: I use linter-gcc, which is an atom.io plugin

Comment: You don't include anything to gcc. You specify include directories for lint in the exact same way you specify them for gcc. If your project compiles with some set of -I flags passed to gcc, it should lint with the exact same set of -I flags passed to lint.